# Neo4j query result cache

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've noticed that when I run a heavy query over and over again, it takes the same duration to finish. This is not typical behavior of databases. Does neo4j cache queries?

Comment: Perhaps share the query, the profile output and the timings. And the Neo4j version that you use.

Comment: thanks Michael! i dont have a specific use case, but a general question..

Comment: Usually the biggest difference in performance comes when the previous query is run the second time. After that, the performance gain is not much, or none at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j caches the store files, node and relationship objects and query plans. However it does not query results by itself, this needs to be done on application side.

Comment: ,what did you mean by "store files" please?

Comment: The files containing the binary representation of your graph, they are located in `data/graph.db`.