# In-Memory Caching of neo4j result for Pagination

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

neo4j Version: 3.5 (can't upgrade to 4.0 as there are some incompatibilities with some apoc libraries)

I previously asked a question regarding pagination and so far it works. The only concern that I have, is the same concern of a previous post ([cypher pagination total result count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973111/cypher-pagination-total-result-count)) wherein to implement paging, there needs to be 2 queries.

A similar question was asked 5 years ago ([Neo4j query result cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646017/neo4j-query-result-cache)) and I am wondering if the same constraint still holds true for version 3.5? The reason I am asking for this is that I find inconsistencies with my pagination approach.

The structure of my query is something like this (as the way neo4jclient can handle it)

```
   MATCH (required match queries)    // let's refer this as REQUIREDMATCH
    CALL apoc.cypher.run( REQUIREDMATCH ) YIELD VALUE
      WITH fields_from_required_match, VALUE.recordCount AS total ORDER BY sortvalue // establishing the sort
         SKIP X LIMIT Y
            OPTIONAL (optional match queries)
               WITH { a,b,c } AS MyObjects, total
                  RETURN collect(distinct MyObjects), total
```

So if you would notice, the REQUIREDMATCH queries are executed twice. I put the SKIP/LIMIT before the optional match so we can specify the range of records we are only getting for optional matches. The problem that I have experienced here is that if the results of my MATCH query is beyond the limit, it won't be picked up.

Say I have one matching result and it is in the 12th index, if I do SKIP 0, LIMIT 10, results would be 0. If I do SKIP 0, LIMIT 50, the result would be 1.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to cache the result of REQUIREDMATCH query and use that cache to get total and SKIP and LIMIT results?
2. As my code works, I suppose that there's no problem. But considering I have issues with returning SKIP and LIMIT result sets, could there be anything that I miss in structuring my query?

Comment: What would you prefer your structure to look like? I'm not sure what `Neo4jClient` can't handle?

Comment: @ChrisSkardon our original query calls the "call apoc.cypher.run" first but neo4jclient doesn't have methods to execute this one first so we arranged it in such a way REQUIREDMATCH->APOC.CYPHER (to get count)->OPTIONALMATCH

I guess the question that I wanted is that we have seen degradation of performance when we implemented paging, partially I think because of the REQUIREDMATCH queries executed twice. Hence my question of is it possible to have one REQUIREDMATCH and get total plus the OPTIONALMATCH with minimal performance hit (it's a  287 ms vs 12 seconds performance loss)

Comment: I know of no limitation that means you can't execute a proc first. Can you maybe raise that in the GH repo as an issue? The question as to performance - you're probably going to have to give more info about your match clauses - 300ms to 12s is substantial and not something I would expect